# How to test the jetpack compose app in release version?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-jetpack-compose

I'm new to compose.

What I've made right now is just two screens transition with animation on button click.

But its lagging in emulator and my phone as well.
So i read somewhere that i need to test it in 'release version' and not 'debug version'. And I also need to 'minify' and 'shrink'.

I don't understand exactly what that means. I tried to do something about the 'minify' and 'shrink' and built apk, but it didn't work. It built two apks named 'app-debug.apk' which is 7 MB and 'app-debug-androidTest.apk' which is little less than 1 MB.

I haven't found a clear explanation of exactly what i need to do. Please help.

Comment: You can add ```signingConfig`` in release version in ```build.gradle``` file and select ```BuildVariant``` Release. it will install release apk. but it will take much time to install app so test when you are at some point when you can test features

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**minifyEnabled** : remove un-use classes, function, activities, and do encryption. and that help when any to decrypt it's not.
make when you use the **minifyEnabled** then write pro-guard rule.

**shrinkResources** : remove un-use resources and decrease apk size